# I want to know if you can receive texts from a blocked number

Tags: iphone

If you have an iPhone how can you receive texts from a blocked number

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Different. You will need to unblock the person in question. To do this, go to Settings -> Messages -> Blocked, and unblock the person. This of course will unblock both calls and text messages.